# How to use vite build use another config file instead of vite.config.js

Tags: vue.js, web, bundler, vite

`vite build` uses the `vite.config.js` to build the bundle, what if I have a `my.config.js`, how can I tell `vite build` to run this config instead of `vite.config.js`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

1.If you have a file named **my.config.js** that you want Vite to use instead of the default **vite.config.js**

your **my.config.js file** is located in the root directory of your project.

2.Open your terminal or command prompt and navigate to the root directory of your project.

3.Run the **vite build** command with the --**config flag**, specifying the path to your custom configuration file.

```
vite build --config my.config.js
```

4.This command tells Vite to use **my.config**.js as the configuration file for the build process

you can provide a custom configuration file to Vite and override the default behavior of using **vite.config.js.**